# Global variables in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, global-variables, parent

```
let check1 = 0;

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  const video = useRef();
  const [check2, setCheck2] = useState(0);
  let check3 = 0;
  
  useEffect(
    () => {
      askPermission().then((record) => {
        if (record) {
          RNSoundLevel.start();
          RNSoundLevel.onNewFrame = (data) => {
            if(check1 < 10) check1++;
            if(check2 < 10) setCheck(check2++);
            if(check3 < 10) check3++;
          }
        }
      });
```

If check1, the value can be read and written normally.

check2 and check3 give the value (0) at the time of the first render.

It seems that it can be solved by using check1, but the code does not seem to be clean.
I want to use check2, is there a way to read it?

Comment: Could you explain the problem clearer? What are you trying to solve and what are your errors?

Comment: if(check1 < 10) check1++;
if(check2 < 10) setCheck(check2++);
if(check3 < 10) check3++;

Only check1 becomes read and write.
check2, check3 read default value(0).

Comment: Let me see if I understood, you're saying that the check2 and check3 value never gets changed?

Comment: Yes. Change and read are initial values.